# Can I specify the downloaded filename from the export URL?

Tags: google-sheets

I can export a sheet in CSV format with a URL like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/export?format=csv&gid={page_id}`, but the downloaded file is automatically 
 named like `{bookname} - {sheetname}.csv`. I would like to specify the filename, for example with a query parameter like `&filename=hoge.csv`. Is there any way?

Comment: unfortunately, not possible

Comment: sad, but thanks anyway @player0