# GAS fileName parameter when export as csv

Tags: google-apps-script

Download sheet as csv. Below is my working code

```js
    function download_CSV() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      var ssID = ss.getId();
      var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Kitchen Doors Feed').getSheetId();

      var csv_format = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export"+
                                                            "?format=csv&"+
                                                            "=csv&"+
                                                            "gid="+sheetId+"";
    
      Logger.log(csv_format)
      return [csv_format];
    }
```

The code above return a download file link. The file is CSV format named same as the Sheet tab to which it refers (example: Sheet1.csv).

I would like to be free to name the file as I pleased (example: mytestfile.csv).

To achieve that I tried to add the parameter ("title=filename") in the url builder (variable "csv_format") as showed below, but doesn't work.

```js
function download_CSV() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ssID = ss.getId();
  var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Kitchen Doors Feed').getSheetId();
 

      var csv_format = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export"+
                                                            "?format=csv&"+
                                                            "=csv&"+
                                                            "title=filename&"+
                                                            "gid="+sheetId+"";
    
      Logger.log(csv_format)
      return [csv_format];
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the actual relationship between `I'm trying to add a parameter that allow to specify the file name` and your showing script. Can you provide more information? For example, can you provide your whole script?

Comment: I agree with Tanaike. Can you also provide more information about your end goal and the expected result?

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry, I have edited my question. Hope make sense. Thanks

Comment: @FernandoLara Lara Sorry, I have edited my question. Hope make sense. Thanks

Comment: @user14484722 consider post the issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:191640&s=created_time:desc) - your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57651311/12511801) and in the comments says that it's no possible either

Comment: Thank you for replying. How are you using your function? Can I ask you about the detailed method for using your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not possible. According to [this other post](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19_h3uYnTGjMBnTzx1wxrcjQ6crYPt0wsqHHnR7WdmsU/export?format=csv&=csv&title=filename&gid=0) the parameter `title` is not listed, therefore it can not be used and that is the reason why the current URL ignores the parameter when you try to use it.

In addition to that, if you try to record the HTTP traffic when clicking the download button in Google Sheets you will see that the request URL only includes the following format:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID/export?format=csv&id=ID&gid=0
```

It looks like the default behavior is that it will take the name from the document itself and would not accept custom names.

In conclusion, it looks like this parameter can not be used for Google Docs, however you could request this as a feature by creating a [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

#### Reference:

- [All Google Docs URL parameters/functions/commands?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19_h3uYnTGjMBnTzx1wxrcjQ6crYPt0wsqHHnR7WdmsU/export?format=csv&=csv&title=filename&gid=0)